# Inserting data with Doctrine - Repository Vs Entity

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I've realized there is a difference between a Doctrine repository and Doctrine entity.

I'm trying to implement simple CRUD actions on a table and was injecting a default Doctrine repository into my controller (without injecting an entity).

For the "Update" action I would first `->find($id)` for the record to update and it would return an instance of the entity for me to bind to my form object.

For the "Create" action I realized I can't `->find($id)` a record to insert (since it doesn't exist) in order to retrieve an instance of the entity for me to bind to my form object.

Is there is an alternate way to insert data using Doctrine without an instance of an entity?  Or is there a way to retrieve an instance of the entity from the repository so I can `->bind()` it to the form?  If the answer to both are no, then I imagine my only options are to inject an instance of the entity to my controller, or to use a custom repository which contains a method which would return an entity to use in the `->bind()` for insertion.

My guess would be to define a custom repository which has a method which retrieves an empty entity instance for use in insertion.  Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Why do you need to inject an instance anywhere? That's what the `new` keyword is for and it is a new entity. Create a new instance of your entity in your controller and bind that. If you don't want to hard code the entity class name in your controller, you can get the entity class name using the repository `getClassName()` method and then create a new instance of that.

Comment: If I did that then that would be an implicit dependency and the next person to work on this code would have a harder time figuring out why the class is  broken after the entity is deleted, moved, renamed, etc.  It would be easy to do it that way and call it a day, but that method is not as maintainable for future development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed by @Crisp in comments, Entities are no more than PHP classes, same for Repositories.
The two are differentiated by their respective role.

You'll never implicitly create a new instance of a Repository because doctrine do it for you across DependencyInjection principles ([Service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html), [Factory](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html), ...).

To create a new database entry, you must create a new instance of the corresponding entity, then store it using `EntityManager::persist` and `EntityManager::flush` methods.

Reuse the same instance of an entity would not give you any benefit, nor make any difference in your project's maintainability.

The entity class itself will never be broken/changed, only instances of them are created, renamed, moved, deleted.
These instances **represents** your database entries, this is the primary interest of use an ORM.

Comment: I'm trying to strictly adhere to best practices on this, maybe I'm understanding "best practices" wrong.  If you need an instance of a particular class in order for something to work it is a dependency.  Aren't explicit dependencies favorable over implicit dependencies.  Isn't the use of the new keyword frowned upon inside of a requested controller because it is an implicit dependency?  Why is it okay to use the `new` keyword` in this situation over others?

Comment: I can understand your logic now. I think that's because entities should be considered as object representations of your database entries rather than real dependencies. I don't really know why we don't have a `EntityManager::getRepository([alias])->getNew()` for example, but the result would be the same as `EntityManager::getRepository([entityAlias])` (a new instance of the corresponding class).

Comment: You can perfectly keep your code following best practices even by adding methods such as create/update/delete in a Repository. This is at your own appreciation.

Comment: +1 @d.lanza38 Think about it this way, if you were not using an ORM you would simply be passing around arrays *representing* the data. You can avoid having to hard code the `new Entity` in a controller by moving the `$form->setObject(new Entity);` into a form factory.

Comment: Thank you, glad to know I'm on the right track at least.  @chalasr I'm already using `EntityManager::getRepository([entityAlias])` but this returns the repository and not the alias.  So I'll go about creating my own repository by implementing `Doctrine\ORM\Repository\RepositoryFactory` and add a method which returns an empty instance of the appropriate entity.  However I'll inject an empty instance of the entity into the repository so the dependency between the entity and repository is explicit as well.

Comment: I realize I might need to blank out the entity object each time I call the new method in order to ensure it is fresh each time.  I'll mark this as the answer because between the answer and comments, it is the answer.  Thank you everyone!